# Convert bin(df) output to dataframe

Tags: r, plyr, sapply, vegan

I have applied the bin function from OneR across all columns of a dataframe. I would now like to convert this to a dataframe. I have tried a few different methods to convert it but I have been unsuccessful.

```
library(vegan)
library(OneR)

data(dune)
dune.vars <- sapply(dune, function(x) bin(x,nbins = 3,method = "content", na.omit = F))

dune.vars <- do.call(cbind.data.frame, dune.vars)
df <- plyr::ldply (dune.vars, data.frame)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out!

```
dune.vars <- as.data.frame(sapply(dune.vars, function(x) cbind(as.vector(bin(x,nbins = 3,method = "content", na.omit = F)))))
```